# Get difference between two unix dates in Python

Tags: python

I want to find the time difference in seconds between two dates of the format : Thu Dec 26 04:46:28 GMT 2013 in python. Will calendar.timegm() help? P.S. I'm new to python and using Python 2.4.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `timedelta` object has a `total_seconds()` method:

```
>>> d1 = "Thu Dec 26 04:46:28 GMT 2013"
>>> d2 = "Thu Dec 26 04:50:28 GMT 2013"
>>> fmt = '%a %b %d %I:%M%:%S %Z %Y'
>>> from datetime import datetime as dt
>>> (dt.strptime(d2, fmt) - dt.strptime(d1, fmt)).total_seconds()
240.0
```

> I'm getting an AttributeError. Guessing that's because i am using
>   python 2.4.3 and the module attribute is unsupported.

<strike>You can use the `seconds` attribute of the object:</strike>

Apparently Python 2.4 doesn't have strptime for `datetime`, but `time` does:

```
>>> import time
>>> t1 = time.strptime(d2, fmt)
>>> t2 = time.strptime(d1, fmt)
>>> dt1 = dt.fromtimestamp(mktime(t1))
>>> dt2 = dt.fromtimestamp(mktime(t2))
>>> (dt1-dt2).total_seconds()
240.0
```

Comment: I'm getting an AttributeError. Guessing that's because i am using python 2.4.3 and the module attribute is unsupported. The exact error is AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'strptime'

Comment: @burhan-khalid: `datetime.datetime` doesn't have the `strptime` method in 2.4.x

Comment: You can use the `strptime` from `time`.

Comment: @user3135731: use `datetime(*time.strptime(timestr)[:6])` directly instead of `datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(time.strftime(timestr, fmt)))` roundtrip that might fail if local timezone is not UTC. Or `calendar.timegm(time.strptime(timestr))` to get seconds since epoch.